# Principle difference between vector::iterator and set::iterator

Tags: c++, stl, vector, iterator, set

I've noticed such a question in one of C++\STL test-paper.

Any ideas?

Probably, that is somehow connected with the fact, that deleting element in collection causes invalidation "all after deleted" iterator in vector and only the iterator of the deleted in set?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 4):

The difference relates much more with the different nature of the containers than with the iterator themselves.

One aspect relates with the "sorted / unsorted" nature of those containers: you cannot modify an element that sits inside a sorted container, since it will compromise the order.

Another aspect relates with the "compact / expanded" storing mechanism: elements in vector are stored all together in a single allocation block, elements in set (or lists) are stored individually. As a consequence, insertion / deletion in vectors cause a change in the displacement of the elements. Insertion / deletion in set or list just causes a relink, with all existing element to keep their place (and hence not invalidating the iterators who refers to them)

Another aspect -always related to the storage- is that vector::iterator are "**random access**": ++i, i+=3, i+=100 takes the same time, since displacements can be arithmetically calculated. In sets (and "linked containers") iterators are just "**bidirectional**": ++i and --i are of immediate calculation, but i+=5 or i+=100 takes a completely different time (requires at least linear loop)

Answer (score 3):

The object to which a `set::iterator` refers is `const`, as it is not permitted to change the value of entries in a `set` as it is ordered (and being allowed to changes the values would potentially break the order). This is not the case for a `vector::iterator`.

For example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <set>

int main()
{
    std::set<int> s;
    std::vector<int> v;

    *v.begin() = 4;
    *s.begin() = 4; // Line 10.
    return 0;
}
```

MSVC++ compiler emits:

> main.cpp(10) : error C3892: 'std::_Tree<_Traits>::begin' : you cannot assign to a variable that is const

g++ compiler emits:

> error: assignment of read-only location ‘s.std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::begin with _Key = int, _Compare = std::less, _Alloc = std::allocator.std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<_Tp>::operator* with _Tp = int’

Comment: Just a clarification note: it's not the iterator that is const (the iterator itself can be changed). It is the value it refers to that is const.

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia, updated (and hopefully clarified). Thanks.